# Tips to replace and soldering the battery connector in pcb

Tags: batteries, connector, soldering, repair

Tips to replace the asus rog gl703 8 pin battery connector, I think using a soldering station that shields nearby circuits with kapton tape and tin paste is a good idea to start with, the board still has some tin on footprints[image][image]What do you recommend me? Any good advice to keep in mind will be useful. The pins are somewhat hidden by the top plate of the connector. Thank in advance and sorry for my bad english[image][image]

[image]

Comment: I added a video in your last question that showed the exact connector being replaced - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hV05M3brCI

Comment: I dont see anything critical nearby, so just use a hot air desoldering station? Obviously on the same side as the exposed pads and not blowing in the direction of the 0402 etc components. If you are feeling nervous you can indeed use peelable solder mask or kapton tape to protect nearby components.

Comment: @Lundin Do you recommend a specific temperature for this type of connector?

Comment: 350°C is the standard recommendation for RoHS solder. However in case of hot air desoldering, it depends a lot on the air flow, so it's hard to tell from station to station.